# Import File to Database in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: python, csv, phpmyadmin

I want to import a file to a phpmyadmin database. It is to have 5 columns: id, url, lat, lon and address. However each line of the file is structured as follows:

```
23947501894 https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1664/23947501894_09e21ac1c4_q.jpg 53.404021 -2.996651 Belgian Merchant Seamen, Queensway (Mersey Tunnel), Liverpool, North West England, England, CH41, United Kingdom
```

Most of the data I want to input is seperated by a space, other than when it gets to the address at the end, where it has many spaces and commas. Is it possible to input this data to the database as is? If so can anyone suggest how I might do this?

I am very new to phpmyadmin and I am using python to do this. Thanks in advance for your help I am very stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to process the text file before importing, since the delimiter also appears unescaped in line with your data.

The good news is that your data format makes this really easy. Take the first four spaces and convert them to a special character (maybe `;` or `~`, something that doesn't appear anywhere else in your data). You can accomplish this with your favorite stream editor or text manipulation program (sed, awk, perl, and python are all good candidates for this work).

There are many ways to do this ([see also these answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155805/sed-replace-first-k-instances-of-a-word-in-the-file) for an idea how many different ways exist, though note that question is about working on an entire *file* and we want to work on individual *lines*), but probably the simplest is by running sed four times:

```
for i in $(seq 4) ; do sed -i -e 's/ /~/' ~/import.csv  ; done
```

**Make sure you do this with a *copy* of the file because this will edit the specified file in-place.**

From your phpMyAdmin Import tab, you'll then use `~` (or whatever separator you used) as the value for "Columns separated with:" and leaving blank all the others except for leaving "auto" at "Lines terminated with:"

Your import settings should look like this (again, substitute whatever character you need to for the delimiter):

[image: Import settings]

Answer (score 0):

Log in PHPMyAdmin, then do:

[Refer Right Frame]
1. Click Database Tab and Create DB 
2. Click Import Tab 
3. Click Browse and select csv file 
4. Change Format from SQL to CSV 
5. Click Go

Comment: How will that help? The incoming data isn't comma separated, so at the very least some settings there need to be changed, but given the data format even that won't finish the job.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch he was stuggling to find option to import CSV, that I showed him, rest he can figure that out.